What is the difference between std::fill_n and std::ranges::fill_n?
I'm having a hard time seeing the practical difference between std::fill_n and std::ranges::fill_n.

Many standard algorithms have a similar ranges counterpart.

Even if there's no meaningful difference other than stricter concept checks, the point is that std::ranges should have alternatives for all algorithms, so that you don't have to touch the old ones ever again.

There are a few main differences that apply to all the std vs std::ranges algorithms:

The ones in std::ranges are constrained with concepts, so are much stricter in what they accept. It is common when migrating code using custom iterators that the iterator isn't quite an input_iterator (usually because of missing something like difference_type) so will need to be updated. The ones in std::ranges also are based on the C++20 iterator concepts, not the C++98 ones - so there are slight differences there too (most notably that you are allowed to have a forward or better iterator that gives you prvalues).

The ones in std::ranges are function objects, not function templates. Technically they're "niebloids", but the only way to implement them to get the required standard behavior is as a function object, and it is likely the case that they will soon be specified as such.


Many of the algorithms have additional differences - most notably accepting a range rather than a pair of iterators. Many also have projection arguments in addition to the callables. Many also have a different return type from their std:: counterpart.
But fill_n specifically doesn't have those extra overloads or arguments or have a distinct return type - std::ranges::fill_n is the same as std::fill_n except for the differences I laid out earlier. You can think of std::ranges::fill_n existing primarily so that every std::meow has a std::ranges::meow counterpart, so that you can wholesale switch to std::ranges without having to think about it.

A cursory investigation leads me to believe std::fill_n(args...) is well-formed iff std::ranges::fill_n(args...)'s constraints are matched, but I might be missing a subtlety

@Caleth No. For instance, output_iterator does not require an iterator category tag, but Cpp17OutputIterator does.

I'd rather use ranges::fill on a views::take. It's at least provides minimum guarantee for not running out of bounds. All iterator based algorithms are susceptible to out-of-bounds UB. ranges::copy is another disappointment; the destination can be simply overrun; a range-based for on views::zip(src,dst) is much safer.

@Red.Wave This is a question about the difference between std::fill_n and std::ranges::fill_n.

The answer is just the question: No practical difference. Safety is my added demand.

@Red.Wave These comments are not really relevant to the topic. You're welcome to express your demands elsewhere.
